# Alternatives to deprecated java method from org.assertj.core.api

Tags: java, assertj

I'm looking for an alternative of the deprecated method `containsOnlyElementsOf`.

It has to check whether the given iterable (a list of Integers in my case) contains only Integers in-between given bounds.

I've tried looking at the [docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/package-summary.html) but didn't find any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnlyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable)) is what you are looking for. The name of the method is indeed confusing. The substitute depends on what you want - you either should use [isSubsetOf](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#isSubsetOf(ELEMENT...)), or [containsOnly](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/ObjectEnumerableAssert.html#containsOnly(ELEMENT...)). Check out the documentation of both, and pick the one you need)

Comment: In the end I opted for iterating over my list of integer and using ```isIn``` on each of the elements.

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnlyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable) suggests alternatives: use ObjectEnumerableAssert.isSubsetOf(Iterable) to check that actual is a subset of given iterable, or if you need to same assertion semantics use ObjectEnumerableAssert.hasSameElementsAs(Iterable).